# Error setting up notifications from S3 bucket to FIFO SQS queue due to required ".fifo" suffix

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

Folks,
I believe I've encountered a minor bug on the newest AWS FIFO SQS, does anyone have a solution for the following error I am getting?

- I've created a FIFO queue on AWS SQS Management Console (us-west-2 region). To create a FIFO queue, SQS mgmt console *requires* that you insert a ".fifo" suffix on the queue's name (which is unusual -- "." is not recommended for naming anything on AWS).
- I've set the appropriate permissions on this queue to receive notifications from a bucket I own on the same region.
- (The error) Went to S3's management console -> chose the appropriate bucket -> clicked on "Properties" -> Events to setup event notifications on "ObjectCreated (All)". When typing the ARN name for the SQS queue it (expectedly) complains about the "." on the queue's name.

I understand I can instead create a standard queue, but I would much rather have a FIFO queue based on my requirements.

Thank you.

Comment: S3 integration with FIFO queues probably isn't supported yet, just like SNS integration with FIFO queues isn't supported yet. This question probably belongs on the AWS support forums.

Answer (score 1):

Fifo queues currently are not compatible to receive notifications.

Check NOTE:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-subscribe-queue-sns-topic.html

Answer (score 1):

Update 30/05/2023, S3 is still not compatible with FIFO queues.

> The following features of AWS services aren't currently compatible
> with FIFO queues:
>
> - Amazon S3 Event Notifications
> - Auto Scaling Lifecycle
> - Hooks AWS IoT Rule Actions
> - AWS Lambda Dead-Letter Queues

Official document
[Compatibility](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-compatibility.html)

Comment: As of 10/07/2023, still getting "Member must satisfy regular expression pattern". I'm trying setting an SNS FIFO topic instead of SQS, but still getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

We cant have a sqs fifo queue as a target for s3 bucket event notifications.

Ref : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-compatibility.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).