# process files put into s3 bucket in AWS lambda in the order in which they were put

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

My current workflow is as follows:

User drops file into s3 bucket -> s3 bucket triggers event to lambda -> lambda processes the file in s3 bucket. It also invokes other lambdas.

I want to handle the scenario where multiple users will drop files in the s3 bucket simultaneously. I want to process the files such that the file put first gets processed first. To handle this, I want the lambda to process each file in a gap of 15 minutes (for example).

So, I want to use SQS to queue the input file drop events. S3 can trigger an event to SQS. A cloudwatch event can trigger a lambda in every 15 minutes, and the lambda can poll the SQS queue for the first s3 file drop event, and process it.

The problem with SQS is that Standard SQS queues do not adhere to order, and FIFO SQS queues are not compatible with S3 (Ref: [Error setting up notifications from S3 bucket to FIFO SQS queue due to required ".fifo" suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383699/error-setting-up-notifications-from-s3-bucket-to-fifo-sqs-queue-due-to-required))

What approach should I use to solve this problem?

Thanks,

Swagatika

Comment: *I want to process the files such that the file put first gets processed first.*  Why?  In large-scale distributed systems, "first" is a concept that becomes vague.

Comment: Does anyone have a workaround? have stuck in a same kind of scenario.

Comment: We came up with the solution where s3 event triggers dummy lambda -> dummy lambda processes the events one by one and writes to an SQS -> SQS queues the messges. A cloudwatch event gets activated every 15 minutes, and triggers the main lambda. This lambda receives teh cloudwatch events and polls sqs for any messages. If there are it picks up the oldest message and processes it.

Answer (score 2):

You could have Amazon S3 trigger an AWS Lambda function, which then pushes the file info into a FIFO Amazon SQS queue.

There is a new capability where SQS can trigger Lambda, but you'd have to experiment to see how/whether that works with FIFO queues. If it works well, that could eliminate the '15 minutes' thing.

Comment: FIFO SQS can not trigger lambda yet (as of today)